# How to send data to local clipboard from a remote SSH session

Tags: linux, macos, unix, shell, clipboard

Most Unix-like systems have a command that will let you pipe/redirect output to the local clipboard/pasteboard, and retrieve from same.  On [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), these commands are

```
pbcopy, pbpaste
```

Is there a way to replicate this functionality while [SSHed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into another server?  That is,

1. I'm using Computer A.
2. I open a terminal window
3. I SSH to Computer B
4. I run a command on Computer B
5. The output of Computer B is redirected or automatically copied to Computer A's clipboard.

And yes, I know I could just (shudder) use my mouse to select the text from the command, but I've gotten so used to the workflow of pipping output directly to the clipboard that I want the same for my remote sessions.

Code is useful, but general approaches are appreciated as well.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673164/209677), alike to [@TrinitronX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962516/4970442) one but without XQuartz, on Linux.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I'm resurrecting this thread because I've been looking for the same kind of solution, and I've found one that works for me. It's a minor modification to a suggestion from [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/05/transfer-clipboard-text-source-code-between-macs-with-ssh/).

In my case, I use Terminal on my local OS X machine to connect to a Linux server via SSH. Like the OP, I wanted to be able to transfer small bits of text from terminal to my local clipboard, using only the keyboard.

The essence of the solution:

```
commandThatMakesOutput | ssh desktop pbcopy
```

When run in an SSH session to a remote computer, this command takes the output of *commandThatMakesOutput* (e.g., [ls](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls), [pwd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd)) and pipes the output to the clipboard of the local computer (the name or IP of "desktop"). In other words, it uses nested SSH: you're connected to the remote computer via one SSH session, you execute the command there, and the remote computer connects to your desktop via a different SSH session and puts the text to your clipboard.

It requires your desktop to be configured as an SSH server (which I leave to you and Google). It's much easier if you've set up ssh keys to facilitate fast ssh usage, preferably using a per-session passphrase, or whatever your security needs require.

Other examples:

```
ls  | ssh desktopIpAddress pbcopy
pwd | ssh desktopIpAddress pbcopy
```

For convenience, I've created a Bash file to shorten the text required after the pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh desktop pbcopy
```

In my case, I'm using a specially-named key.

I saved it with the file name *cb* (my mnemonic (ClipBoard). Put the script somewhere in your path, make it executable and voilà:

```
ls | cb
```

Comment: I often to this in vim. To do so, select what you want to copy in visual mode, then type: `:'<,'>w !ssh desktop pbcopy`

Comment: @MikeBrennan When you have the text selected, why don't you just press cmd+C (or whatever copy key you have set)? ...

Comment: Like this it only really works when your desktop has a static IP and is reachable from the box you ssh'd into. That's never the case for me.

Comment: Wouldn't the other way around be easier?  ssh user@remote 'commandThatMakesOutput' |pbcopy

Comment: I needed the `-e none` ssh flag described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210615/how-to-copy-file-contents-to-the-local-clipboard-from-a-file-in-a-remote-machine

Comment: In case you want to use it on Windows, (I know the OP didn't ask), you can also use `commandThatMakesOutput | clip` (eg; `ssh -t root@$host "cat /your/file" | clip`).

Comment: It works for me perfectly. I suggest ssh'ing from your client machine to host machine first, before doing `| ssh desktop pbcopy`.

Comment: For anyone having trouble getting this to work on MacOS, you may need to use `reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy` instead of just `pbcopy`. https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard

Answer (score 172):

My favorite way is `ssh [remote-machine] "cat log.txt" | xclip -selection c`. This is most useful when you don't want to (or can't) ssh from remote to local.

On Cygwin, `ssh [remote-machine] "cat log.txt" > /dev/clipboard`.

A helpful comment from nbren12:

> It is almost always possible to setup a reverse ssh connection using SSH port forwarding. Just add `RemoteForward 127.0.0.1:2222 127.0.0.1:22` to the server's entry in your local `.ssh/config`, and then execute `ssh -p 2222 127.0.0.1` on the remote machine, which will then redirect the connection to the local machine. – nbren12

Comment: +1: So much easier than other solutions when a reverse SSH connection isn't possible!

Comment: You deserve more likes for that extremely simple solution!

Comment: For those of us on Mac OSX, `ssh [remote-machine] "cat log.txt" | pbcopy`

Comment: As per this report [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-08/msg01400.html), I had to use `cat` to get this to work on cygwin Windows 8: `ssh [remote-machine] "cat log.txt" | cat > /dev/clipboard` (of course, my remote command wasn't `cat`; it was something else inside a vagrant virtual machine so I actually ran `vagrant ssh -c "command" | cat > /dev/clipboard`)

Comment: Top answer, better then reverse ssh.

Comment: It is _almost_ always possible to setup a reverse ssh connection using SSH port forwarding. Just add `RemoteForward 127.0.0.1:2222 127.0.0.1:22` to the servers entry in your local `.ssh/config`, and then execute `ssh -p 2222 127.0.0.1` on the remote machine, which will then redirect the connection to the local machine.

Comment: awesome! this is great. just note that the log.txt is the file on the remote host, i am unsure if you can specify the file path but most likely

Comment: But what to do when the file is very deep like inside two nested sshs which require passwords and then inside a user account which again require a password ?

Comment: On WSL: `ssh [remote-machine] "cat log.txt" | clip.exe`

Comment: Added: `cb.zerkon() { ssh zerkon "$1" | xclip -selection zerkon -in }` to my .zshrc file after seeing this, where zerkon is a host I commonly ssh into.

Answer (score 33):

I found a great solution that doesn't require a reverse SSH connection!

You can use [xclip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) on the remote host, along with SSH X11 forwarding and XQuartz on the OS X system.

To set this up:

1. Install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) (I did this with [soloist + pivotal_workstation::xquartz recipe](https://github.com/pivotal/pivotal_workstation), but you don't have to)
2. Run XQuartz.app
3. Open XQuartz Preferences ([image: kb_command]+`,`)
4. Make sure *"Enable Syncing"* and *"Update Pasteboard when CLIPBOARD changes"* are checked
   [image: XQuartz Preferences window example]
5. `ssh -X remote-host "echo 'hello from remote-host' | xclip -selection clipboard"`

Comment: How is this any different from `ssh remote-host "echo 'hello from remote-host' | pbcopy`? 
This would be an excellent answer if it would work something like this: 
`ssh -X remote-host` then on the remote host:
`echo 'hello from remote-host' | xclip -selection clipboard`

Comment: @KasperSouren. I believe it does work how you are hoping.  The ` | xclip` is inside the double quotes.

Comment: In 2016, this is obviously THE best, no-frill solution. Forget other, reverse-ssh based solutions.

Comment: Is there a way to do this w/o it just being a one-off command?  I want to be logged into my remote server in an interactive session over ssh and then be able to send to my local clipboard arbitrarily.  Does that require reverse ssh?

Comment: @Kvass: As long as you're using `-X` for X11 Forwarding over SSH, X11 programs will be able to update your clipboard via the XQuartz settings above.  The one-off command is to demonstrate that sending something via `echo` to the remote host's clipboard via `xclip` does work & should sync to your local SSH client host.  Note as @gdw2 says, "The `| xclip` is inside the double quotes".   As such, it will execute as a command on the remote server to send something to it's clipboard.

Comment: This solution works, but XQuartz *hammers* the CPU. Burns a lot of extra power all the time for the occasional benefit of copying to the clipboard.

Comment: @Br.Bill Yes, of course, the X11 Forwarding + XQuartz setup is providing more than just clipboard sync capability.  (_Hint for readers_: Try running an X11 program like `xeyes` on the remote system)  This could be desired or not, depending on your use case.  If you don't require full X11 client + server support, and just want a no-frills local LAN network-based clipboard you might try [`remotestash`](https://github.com/roznet/remotestash) instead.

Answer (score 33):

## Reverse tunnel port on ssh server

All the existing solutions either need:

- X11 on the client (if you have it, `xclip` on the server works great) or
- the client and server to be in the same network (which is not the case if you're at work trying to access your home computer).

Here's another way to do it, though you'll need to modify how you ssh into your computer.

I've started using this and it's nowhere near as intimidating as it looks so give it a try.

### Client (ssh session startup)

```
ssh username@server.com -R 2000:localhost:2000
```

(hint: make this a keybinding so you don't have to type it)

### Client (another tab)

```
nc -l 2000 | pbcopy
```

Note: if you don't have `pbcopy` then just `tee` it to a file.

### Server (inside SSH session)

```
cat some_useful_content.txt | nc localhost 2000
```

### Other notes

Actually even if you're in the middle of an ssh session there's a way to start a tunnel but i don’t want to scare people away from what really isn’t as bad as it looks. But I'll add the details later if I see any interest

Comment: +1 -- that's pretty neat.  However -- the `cat some_useful_content.txt | nc localhost 2000` command seems to hang when I do this.  I need to manually ctr-c to stop it, and it's only then that the content gets to my client clip/pasteboard

Comment: It will wait until someone dequeues the data at the other end.

Comment: Actually I think I misunderstood your question. I'm not sure why that happens.

Comment: `nc -l -p` works for me, but just `nc -l` does not. And I have the problem of @AlanStorm, too.

Comment: I solved the problem of hanging netcat by specifying `-c`. I use GNU netcat installed by brew.

Comment: Was recently trying and using pbcopy worked fine for me
`ssh <remote host_name> "cat <remote file_name_with_path>" | pbcopy
`

Comment: Like I said, you can’t do that if you’re at work sshing into your home computer.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to automate most of this in my `~/.ssh/config`!  Just add these lines under the host:`RemoteForward 2000 localhost:2000 \n
  LocalCommand /bin/bash -c 'nc -z localhost 2000 && echo "pasteboard port 2000 listener already active" || while true; do nc -l localhost 2000 | pbcopy; echo updated_pasteboard; done' & \n
  PermitLocalCommand yes`.  That starts the port forwarding automatically when you ssh to the host and runs the listener in the background.  The listener never exits by itself but that seems okay and it checks to prevent duplicates listeners.

Comment: what if there is no `nc` on the remote?

Comment: @AlanaStorm and others, using `nc -N localhost 2000` solved this for me. The `-N` option to "shutdown(2) the network socket after EOF on the input" is present in the Debian port I'm using, but also in the BSD version on which it's based.

Answer (score 12):

If you use [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) on the Mac, there is an easier way. This functionality is built into iTerm2's [Shell Integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) capabilities via the `it2copy` command:

```
Usage: it2copy
          Copies to clipboard from standard input
       it2copy filename
          Copies to clipboard from file
```

To make it work,

1. choose **iTerm2-->Install Shell Integration** menu item while logged into the remote host (so that it runs `curl -L https://iterm2.com/shell_integration/install_shell_integration_and_utilities.sh | bash`), to install it to your own account.
2. Follow the instructions to refresh your environment (e.g. `source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh`).

Once that is done, you'll have access to `~/.iterm2/it2copy`, as well as a bunch of other aliased commands that provide cool functionality.

The other solutions here are good workarounds but this one is so painless in comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I never got around for searching for this functionality in it2.

Comment: Emphasis: __while logged into the remote host__

Comment: I just tried this. It really does work if you are patient enough to install it. I've tried to make the post a little bit more copy-paste friendly. Hope @Br.Bill is ok with that. Great tip, I like it more than my generic way. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmmmm, the one downside to this is that if have to ssh to lots of different machines it can get tiresome. But it doesn't need root access so installing server side programs is not an issue.

Comment: Appreciate the re-crafting, @SridharSarnobat !

Answer (score 9):

There are various tools to access X11 selections, including [xclip](http://xclip.sourceforge.net/) and [XSel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/).  Note that X11 traditionally has multiple selections, and most programs have some understanding of both the clipboard and primary selection (which are not the same).  Emacs can work with the secondary selection too, but that's rare, and nobody really knows what to do with cut buffers...

```
$ xclip -help
Usage: xclip [OPTION] [FILE]...
Access an X server selection for reading or writing.

  -i, -in          read text into X selection from standard input or files
                   (default)
  -o, -out         prints the selection to standard out (generally for
                   piping to a file or program)
  -l, -loops       number of selection requests to wait for before exiting
  -d, -display     X display to connect to (eg localhost:0")
  -h, -help        usage information
      -selection   selection to access ("primary", "secondary", "clipboard" or "buffer-cut")
      -noutf8      don't treat text as utf-8, use old unicode
      -version     version information
      -silent      errors only, run in background (default)
      -quiet       run in foreground, show what's happening
      -verbose     running commentary

Report bugs to <astrand@lysator.liu.se>
```

```
$ xsel -help
Usage: xsel [options]
Manipulate the X selection.

By default the current selection is output and not modified if both
standard input and standard output are terminals (ttys).  Otherwise,
the current selection is output if standard output is not a terminal
(tty), and the selection is set from standard input if standard input
is not a terminal (tty). If any input or output options are given then
the program behaves only in the requested mode.

If both input and output is required then the previous selection is
output before being replaced by the contents of standard input.

Input options
  -a, --append          Append standard input to the selection
  -f, --follow          Append to selection as standard input grows
  -i, --input           Read standard input into the selection

Output options
  -o, --output          Write the selection to standard output

Action options
  -c, --clear           Clear the selection
  -d, --delete          Request that the selection be cleared and that
                        the application owning it delete its contents

Selection options
  -p, --primary         Operate on the PRIMARY selection (default)
  -s, --secondary       Operate on the SECONDARY selection
  -b, --clipboard       Operate on the CLIPBOARD selection

  -k, --keep            Do not modify the selections, but make the PRIMARY
                        and SECONDARY selections persist even after the
                        programs they were selected in exit.
  -x, --exchange        Exchange the PRIMARY and SECONDARY selections

X options
  --display displayname
                        Specify the connection to the X server
  -t ms, --selectionTimeout ms
                        Specify the timeout in milliseconds within which the
                        selection must be retrieved. A value of 0 (zero)
                        specifies no timeout (default)

Miscellaneous options
  -l, --logfile         Specify file to log errors to when detached.
  -n, --nodetach        Do not detach from the controlling terminal. Without
                        this option, xsel will fork to become a background
                        process in input, exchange and keep modes.

  -h, --help            Display this help and exit
  -v, --verbose         Print informative messages
  --version             Output version information and exit

Please report bugs to <conrad@vergenet.net>.
```

In short, you should try `xclip -i`/`xclip -o` or `xclip -i -sel clip`/`xclip -o -sel clip` or `xsel -i`/`xsel -o` or `xsel -i -b`/`xsel -o -b`, depending on what you want.

Comment: To add to @ephemient 's post:


In order to use xclip & xsel with a remote host, you can use X11 Forwarding like so: `ssh -C -X user@remote-host`.

If running xclip on the remote side doesn't seem to be working, make sure `X11Forwarding yes` is set in the remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Also make sure `xauth` is installed on the remote side.  For a headless machine, you can install `xauth` and `xvfb`.

Comment: Here's a [description](https://defuse.ca/blog/2012/04/clipboard-over-ssh-with-vim/) with extra details plus vim key bindings.

Comment: @TrinitronX oh wow - banging my head against a wall, thanks for the `xvfb` mention. I was running a headless server, so X11 must not have been running!

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution based on an SSH reverse tunnel, [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), and [xclip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip).

First create a script (for example, clipboard-daemon.sh) on your workstation:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=3333

NUM=`netstat -tlpn 2>/dev/null | grep -c " ${HOST}:${PORT} "`
if [ $NUM -gt 0 ]; then
    exit
fi

while [ true ]; do
    nc -l ${HOST} ${PORT} | xclip -selection clipboard
done
```

And start it in the background.

```
./clipboard-daemon.sh &
```

It will start [`nc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) piping output to xclip and respawning the process after receiving a portion of data.

Then start the SSH connection to the remote host:

```
ssh user@host -R127.0.0.1:3333:127.0.0.1:3333
```

While logged in on the remote box, try this:

```
echo "this is test" >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/3333
```

Then try to paste on your workstation.

You can of course write a wrapper script that starts *clipboard-daemon.sh* first and then the SSH session. This is how it works for me.

Comment: This solution is the one that worked the best for me. it is not too complicated and works properly.

Comment: Best solution in my opinion. You don't have to worry about allowing reverse ssh connection which has security implications, and the infinite loop is a nice touch.

Comment: I like the bash's TCP output, but for local I'm just using `nc -l` directly

Answer (score 7):

Allow me to add a solution that if I'm not mistaken was not suggested before.

**It does not require the client to be exposed to the internet (no reverse connections), nor does it use any xlibs on the server and is implemented completely using ssh's own capabilities (no 3rd party bins)**

It involves:

1. Opening a connection to the remote host, then creating a fifo file on it and waiting on that fifo in parallel (same actual TCP connection for everything).
2. Anything you echo to that fifo file ends up in your local clipboard.
3. When the session is done, remove the fifo file on the server and cleanly terminate the connections together.

The solution utilizes ssh's ControlMaster functionality to use just one TCP connection for everything so it will even support hosts that require a password to login and prompt you for it just once.

Edit: as requested, the code itself:

Paste the following into your bashrc and use `sshx host` to connect.

On the remote machine `echo SOMETHING > ~/clip` and hopefully, SOMETHING will end up in the local host's clipboard.

*You will need the `xclip` utility on your **local** host.*

```bash
_dt_term_socket_ssh() {
    ssh -oControlPath=$1 -O exit DUMMY_HOST
}
function sshx {
    local t=$(mktemp -u --tmpdir ssh.sock.XXXXXXXXXX)
    local f="~/clip"
    ssh -f -oControlMaster=yes -oControlPath=$t $@ tail\ -f\ /dev/null || return 1
    ssh -S$t DUMMY_HOST "bash -c 'if ! [ -p $f ]; then mkfifo $f; fi'" \
        || { _dt_term_socket_ssh $t; return 1; }
    (
    set -e
    set -o pipefail
    while [ 1 ]; do
        ssh -S$t -tt DUMMY_HOST "cat $f" 2>/dev/null | xclip -selection clipboard
    done &
    )
    ssh -S$t DUMMY_HOST \
        || { _dt_term_socket_ssh $t; return 1; }
    ssh -S$t DUMMY_HOST "rm $f"
    _dt_term_socket_ssh $t
}
```

More detailed explanation is on my website:

https://xicod.com/2021/02/09/clipboard-over-ssh.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28307525)

Comment: @radrow thanks for the comment, I updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution of all, if you're on OS X using Terminal and you've been ssh'ing around in a remote server and wish to grab the results of a text file or a log or a csv, simply:

1) `Cmd-K` to clear the output of the terminal

2) `cat <filename>` to display the contents of the file

3) `Cmd-S` to save the Terminal Output

You'll have the manually remove the first line and last line of the file, but this method is a bit simpler than relying on other packages to be installed, "reverse tunnels" and trying to have a static IP, etc.

Comment: +1 for a useful technique I've used myself, bit it does force you to lose your terminal history and (as mentioned) the first/last line problem is a little fiddly.

Comment: Agreed @AlanStorm

Comment: The more significant problem with this approach is that it will only save the number of lines that your terminal buffer retains. Often that’s not a problem but if you’re trying to grab the contents of a log file then you may run out of capacity,

Comment: That's true @Sridhar-Sarnobat , it's not a very good solution in general. I just use `scp`!

Comment: Replace step 3 with `Cmd-A` (select-all) and `Cmd-C` to copy to clipboard. At first, I think `Cmd-A` will just select visible screen's text, but it does select all instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a one-liner, but it doesn't **require any extra SSH connection**.

- install `netcat` if necessary
- use [termbin](http://termbin.com/): `cat ~/some_file.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`. This will copy the output to the `termbin` website and prints the URL to your output.
- visit that URL from your computer, and you get your output

Of course, do not use it for sensitive content.

Comment: Wow that’s a very creative solution.

Answer (score 4):

This answer develops both upon [the chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629316/4376643) by adding more security.

That answer discussed the general form,

```
<command that makes output> | \
    ssh <user A>@<host A> <command that maps stdin to clipboard>
```

Where security may be lacking is in the `ssh` permissions allowing `<user B>` on `host B>` to `ssh` into `host A` and execute *any* command.

Of course `B` to `A` access may already be gated by an `ssh` key, and it may even have a password.  But another layer of security can restrict the scope of allowable commands that `B` can execute on `A`, e.g. so that `rm -rf /` cannot be called.  (This is especially important when the `ssh` key *doesn't* have a password.)

Fortunately, `ssh` has a built-in feature called **command restriction** or **forced command**. See [ssh.com](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh), or
this [Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands).

The solution below shows the general form solution along with `ssh` **command restriction** enforced.

### Example solution with *command restriction* added

This security enhanced solution follows the general form - the call from the `ssh` session on `host-B` is simply:

```
cat <file> | ssh <user-A>@<host A> to_clipboard
```

The rest of this shows the setup to get that to work.

#### Setup of **ssh command restriction**

Suppose the user account on `B` is `user-B`, and B has an ssh key `id-clip`, that has been created in the usual way (`ssh-keygen`).

Then in `user-A`'s ssh directory there is a file

```
/home/user-A/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

that recognizes the key `id-clip` and allows `ssh` connection.

Usually the contents of each line `authorized_keys` is exactly the public key being authorized, e.g., the contents of `id-clip.pub`.

However, to enforce **command restriction** that public key content is prepended (on the same line) by the command to be executed.
In our case:

```
command="/home/user-A/.ssh/allowed-commands.sh id-clip",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-user-rc,no-x11-forwarding,no-pty <content of file id-clip.pub>
```

The designated command `"/home/user-A/.ssh/allowed-commands.sh id-clip"`, and *only* that designated command, is executed whenever key `id-clip` is used initiate an `ssh` connection to `host-A` - *no matter what command is written the `ssh` command line*.

The command indicates a script file `allowed-commands.sh`, and the contents of that that script file is

```
#/bin/bash
#
# You can have only one forced command in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Use this
# wrapper to allow several commands.

Id=${1}

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    "to-clipboard")
          notify-send "ssh to-clipboard, from ${Id}"
        cat | xsel --display :0 -i -b
          ;;
    *)
        echo "Access denied"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

The original call to `ssh` on machine `B` was

```
... | ssh <user-A>@<host A> to_clipboard
```

The string `to-clipboard` is passed to `allowed-commands.sh` by the environment variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.
Addition, we have passed the name of the key, `id-clip`, from the line in `authorized_keys`which is only accessed by `id-clip`.

The line

```
          notify-send "ssh to-clipboard, from ${Id}"
```

is just a popup messagebox to let you know the clipboard is being written - that's probably a good security feature too.  (`notify-send` works on Ubuntu 18.04, and maybe not others).

In the line

```
cat | xsel --display :0 -i -b
```

The parameter `--display :0` is necessary, because the process doesn't have its own X display with a clipboard,
so it must be specified explicitly.  This value `:0` happens to work on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) with the [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) window server.  On other setups it might not work.  For a standard X server [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48216/18577) might help.

#### `host-A` `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` parameters

Finally a few parameters in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on host `A` that should be set to ensure permission to connect, and permission to use an `ssh`-key only without a password:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AllowUsers user-A
```

To make the `sshd` server reread the configuration

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

or

```
sudo service sshd.service restart
```

#### Conclusion

It's some effort to set it up, but other functions besides `to-clipboard` can be constructed in parallel with the same framework.

Comment: The Xsel with remoteforwarding was the only answer that worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 running i3 locally.  No X11 forwarding needed.

Answer (score 3):

[rhileighalmgren's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/how-to-send-data-to-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session/6629316#6629316) is good, but pbcopy will annoyingly copy the last "\n" character. I use [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(Unix)) to strip out the last character to prevent this:

```
#!/bin/bash
head -c -1 |  ssh desktop pbcopy
```

My full solution is here: http://taylor.woodstitch.com/linux/copy-local-clipboard-remote-ssh-server/

Comment: `pbcopy` is not meant to make judgments about what it copies, so it makes sense that it includes everything you give it.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at taylor.woodstitch.com."*. The domain `taylor.woodstitch.com` probably expired.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone googling their way to this:
The best solution in this day and age seem to be [lemonade](https://github.com/lemonade-command/lemonade)

Various solutions is also mentioned in the neovim help text for [clipboard-tool](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/c1fbc2ddf15b2f44b615f90b2511349ab974cb83/runtime/doc/provider.txt#L198)

Answer (score 2):

[Far Manager Linux port](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l) supports synchronizing clipboard between local and remote host. You just open local far2l, do "ssh somehost" inside, run remote far2l in that ssh session and get remote far2l working with your local clipboard.

It supports Linux, *BSD and OS X; I made a [special putty build](https://github.com/unxed/putty4far2l) to utilize this functionality from windows also.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working over e.g. a pod in a Kubernetes cluster and not direct SSH, so that there is no way for your to do a file transfer, you could use `cat` and then save the terminal output as text. For example in macOS you can do Shell -> Export as text.