# copy/paste between two instances of console vim

Tags: linux, vim

I have 2 opened windows with ssh sessions to the same remote linux box (putty). Console vim editor is running in both windows. I'd like to yank text in one window and paste it in another window.
I don't like to copy/paste terminal screen using mouse. Are there any functionality in vim to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If both `vim` sessions are running on the same system, you can write a portion of the buffer to a file in one session (`:w tmp`), then read the file into the buffer in the other (`:r tmp`). If they're running in two different directories, you'll need to specify a full path name.

A simple `:w tmp` will write the entire contents of the buffer. To write just a subset, you can specify a range of lines. You might use `ma` to set a marker at the beginning of the region and `mb` to set another at the end, and then

```
:'a,'bw tmp
```

to write that region to a file. Or you can set a marker at the beginning (say, `mx`), move to the end, and:

```
:'x,.w tmp
```

Or you can specify line numbers; there are a *lot* of options. It's not as convenient as direct copy-and-paste, but it works.

Yet another alternative: Since both `vim` sessions are running on the same system, you can run a single `vim` session for both files, using tabs or windows; then you can directly copy-and-paste between them without leaving `vim`.

Comment: just tried to do this. :w tmp always writes whole string to file tmp file even if I've yanked only one word. But solution is interesting, thanks!

Comment: @Sandro: Good point; I glossed over that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to copy the text from your terminal, so use your mouse or something like tmux which will allow you to copy arbitrarily text from your terminal using only your keyboard.

There may be a way to copy over SSH: [Getting Items on the Local Clipboard from a Remote SSH Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/getting-items-on-the-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session)

But I think you'd have a hard time linking it into Vim. I'd personally recommend tmux on your local machine, ssh inside, then copy the text using tmux.

Comment: Actualy both instances of vim are running on the same remote machine.... maybe they somehow can share some register....

Comment: Ah, I see! You can use `writefile(split(@x, "\n"), fname)` to write a register to a file, `@x` being the register. And you can read from a file with `let @x = join(readfile(fname), "\n")`. So, if `fname` is some common path, you can rig up some mappings to those two little bits of VimL and share registers with them. Yank into `"x`, write, and then in the other session perform the read and paste from `"x`. If that sounds good to you I can write up some VimL for it. Looks like Keith Thompson has the same idea though!

Answer (score 1):

It's done automatically through the system's clipboard.  So if you `ssh` from machine A to machine B you can copy and paste from a Vim running on A to a Vim running on B, and the other way around, provided that:

- machine A is running an X server
- your `ssh` connection forwards X11 requests
- your Vims on both machines are compiled with `+clipboard` and `+xterm_clipboard`
- you have something like this in your `vimrc`s on both machines: `set clipboard=unnamedplus,autoselect`

It also works if you try pasting from one instance of Vim to another on the same machine running X, or on the same machine running Windows (for different reasons).

It doesn't work in a Linux console.  I also don't know if it still works when you cross from Windows to X.