# Copying from VIM over multiple VIM instances in multiple nested tmux sessions on ssh remotes

Tags: linux, macos, vim, ssh, tmux

i have a little difficult problem with vim inside tmux inside tmux.
To explain my problem, i think it's better to illustrate my setup first

```
+----------+       +-----------+
| vim left |       | vim right | (vim 7.3)
+----------+--+    +-----------+-+
|  tmux left  |    | tmux right  | (tmux 1.6)
+-------------++   +-------------++
|   ssh left   |   |   ssh right  |
+--------------++  +--------------+-+
|   tmux left   |  |   tmux right   | (tmux 2.8)
+----------------+ +----------------+
|   iTerm left   | |   iTerm right  |
+----------------+-+----------------+
|         Hostsystem - macOS        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I have two pivot monitors for source code and one iTerm per monitor.
I run tmux on each of the terminals for multiplexing. I didn't like the iTerm splitting and tabbing functions, because i often work with linux workstations, servers via ssh. So i love to have tmux running everywhere for all the fancy splitting, tabbing, etc. . So i only have to remember one set of shortcuts and not many different shortcuts for different terminals (iTerm, Terminator, xterm) but for the same actions.
So as i said, on every of the iTerms i start a tmux session.

Now im working on a remote server, so i connect to them via ssh in both iTerms. The left and right one.

And now, i think you can guess it, i start tmux on each ssh session, so i can split my screen directly on the server and reattach to the sessions, if there are some network connectivity issues and i lose my ssh connection.

Because i have some programming todo, i fire up vim on both terminals.

Finally everything said and explained, i come to my real problem.
How can i get copy (yank) working in vim (inside tmux, inside a ssh session inside an outer tmux session inside a iTerm instance on my macOS host), so it uses my macOS clipboard.

For simplicity, i use the same `.vimrc` on all of my systems. Beside some other configs i have configured that vim **always** uses the system clipboard instead of it's own buffers.

In the `.tmux.conf` on my mac i have configured `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /usr/local/bin/bash"` to get the system clipboard working.

And as long as i'm working on my mac, everything works fine and i can copy from vim inside tmux to my system clipboard.

```
+--------------+   +--------------+
|   vim left   |   |   vim right  | (vim 8.0)
+--------------++  +--------------+-+
|   tmux left   |  |   tmux right   | (tmux 2.8)
+----------------+ +----------------+
|   iTerm left   | |   iTerm right  |
+----------------+-+----------------+
|         Hostsystem - macOS        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

But when i'm connecting to the remote server, copying stops working for me. And this is really killing me.

You can find the my `.tmux.conf` on my local macOS [here](https://github.com/cedi/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf). 
The `.tmux.conf` of the remote tmux can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/cedi/b550bf2034e9ff0e9d2b5587faaf94d0). 
My `.vimrc` can be found [here](https://github.com/cedi/-vim/blob/master/vimrc).

I hope that helps you understanding my problem. And i hope someone can help me.
I know i can copy using the iTerms-Copy function, holding the opt-key pressed while selecting with the mouse. But this is a not so optimal and only a very limited workaround.

Comment: it is a bit a wild guess, since i have not tested it. But i think you actually copy to the clipboard of the server. If your host ist configured as a ssh server, you could send it back there over ssh (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/getting-items-on-the-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session). You could possible send text from your vim to the command with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575545/vim-pipe-selected-text-to-shell-cmd-and-receive-output-on-vim-info-command-line. But as I said, wild guess, but i hope it helps you anyway.

Comment: The answer is always the same, X-forwarding.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but it is probably relevant: [One Vim ... just one](http://vimeo.com/4446112)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UBesBPNh