# Remote SSH Pipe to Local Text Editor

Tags: macos, ssh, pipe, bbedit

Is there a way I can pipe output on a server to my localhost workstation editor?

I am using `bbedit` as an editor and would like to pipe backwards through my terminal to my editor.

It is very similar to this:  [How to send data to local clipboard from a remote SSH session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/how-to-send-data-to-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session)

There are terminal commands for `bbedit`: **bbedit command-line tool: invoke BBEdit from anywhere in the Unix command line to open files or sftp/ftp URLs**

https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/featuresadmin.html

So I'm thinking there might be a way of doing this, even with a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like `rbbedit` work for you? From your description it sounds like it might, although I regret I can't be sure.

https://github.com/cngarrison/rbbedit

Another idea might be to use a Shell Worksheet, and from within the worksheet, `ssh` to your remote host. Then, the output of whatever you do on the remote host is available in the worksheet. (Note, though, that worksheets don't do terminal emulation.)

Comment: The latter seems to be the best thing so far.  I need to output various items from scripts, and I want to avoid making files on the server.  So basically from the server directly into BBEdit as an unnamed file or local temp file.