# How to trigger a local command from remote ssh PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I connect from my company laptop (with WSL+bash) to a corporate Linux server via SSH as usual `ssh user@remote.host` (I have my local rsa public key supplied in the remote user's .ssh/authorized_keys so I don't have to give a password though I don't know if this matters here).

Now I would like the remote shell-prompt (preferably using `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable in the remote `~/.bashrc`) to trigger a command or script on my local machine. The corporate server has no outside world access so I cannot just create an "opposite" ssh connection. I hope to somehow utilize the existing session that I do connect to the server with.

The closest calls that I've managed to get to seem to be the following manuals about a reverse SSH tunnel along with `netcat` listening - on SO:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/how-to-send-data-to-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session/49890019#49890019) and on baeldung:
[www.baeldung.com/linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/local-data-remote-ssh-session#bd-2-netcat). Unfortunately there is even no `nc` in the server's distro so I stuck there.

1. Could I ask for a step by step example not using `nc` for it, thus hopefully, some alternative method?
2. Could I also ask to indicate all the precise commands' segments, like what localhost I should actually specify on the remote end of the tunnel, and so on? In fact I have struggled with many more variations of that ssh tunnel (e.g. `ssh -RfN ...`) taken from the net but with no success.
3. Is it even possible to achieve (perhaps some other way - not with a reverse tunnel), assuming that the corporate host might have some restrictions imposed against it? Or the server configuration should not technically hinder this technique itself?

I admit I don't clearly understand that tunneling mechanism. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you make the remote connection finish with some code, the local machine sees this code, run the command, connect again? It does not seem to be a good use case to have machine talking with each other while both behave as server and client at the same time.

Comment: I need kind of a real-time feedback from the remote session while I'm regularly working out there. Reconnecting gazillion of times for each individual shell command seems not a practical solution.

Comment: Maybe not as impractical as you think. SSH can be told to cache transports and reuse them for new sessions -- see `ControlSocket` configuration knobs. Much, _much_ faster to run a new remote command over an already-open transport than to start a whole new connection.

Comment: BTW, if you can't do a reverse _TCP_ tunnel, you might still look into whether you can set up a reverse forwarded socket. (And you generally don't need `nc` if your remote shell is bash -- the `/dev/tcp` abstraction can be used to do much of what nc does with only shell builtins. Even if your remote bash isn't compiled with that feature turned on, it's trivial to build your own `nc` in Python if the remote system provides a Python interpreter).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I utilized your hint with `ControlMaster auto`  and mux'ing ssh connections but from the remote end -> to the local (boosting the reverse tunnel solution). Only now it works like magic - the feedback is virtually instantaneous. Thank you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a ssh server on your WSL, and run following command :

```
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 your-corporate-linux-server ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@localhost hostname
```

Above command ssh to your-corporate-linux-server, then from there connects back to you WSL, and shows your WSL's hostname.

You need to create ssh key pair on your-corporate-linux-server, and put public key in your WSL's authorized_keys.

Once above command works, you can work on COMMAND_PROMPT.

Comment: Although I created an opposite ssh key-pair and added id_rsa.pub to WSL user's authorized_keys I'm struggling with `Permission denied (publickey)`. Even full debug logs are vague to me. This seems to be a bigger deal... Unfortunately I can't upload here 60 lines of logs.

Comment: Can you copy Linux server’s private key to wsl and test wsl ssh server locally?

Comment: How dumb am I! Thank you for the local test idea - I could not self-ssh in the first place (I could with `PasswordAuthentication on` but not with a public key). After a short SO research I've found the cause: `chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` made my day. Now it's working both locally and from the remote server-loop. Thank you a lot for your help, my appreciation!