Copy to clipboard from PHP CLI (xclip on linux command line not working for me)
I am trying to write a script that uses regex filters to clean up the lyrics of a song (meaning, remove chord markers and the like) and then copy the result to the system clipboard so that a Paste operation can be used to output the result into (say) a text message, a document, or whatever.
Using articles like this https://www.studytonight.com/linux-guide/use-linux-xclip-command-to-copy-and-paste-directly-to-the-terminal as a source, I am having trouble with xclip on ubuntu 24.04.
php ./lyrics.php /googleDrive/SongBook/Shout\ for\ Joy\ All\ the\ Earth.pro | xclip -selection clipboard
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Error: Can't open display: (null)

Apparently, xclip in this environment still wants the display environment, and I have not found a switch to turn that off (I thought --selection clipboard was to do that).
Any clues how I can accomplish the goal?  Perhaps another way to copy to the system clipboard from PHP?  (BTW on MacOs [Darwin], pbpaste works for me.  But I think that's a Mac thing... I cannot find it with apt search.)

How do you expect to do it without the DISPLAY variable? All X applications and utilities need this to interact with the window system.

Why isn't the DISPLAY environment variable set? What is "this environment"?

PHP is irrelevant to this. xclip doesn't care where its input comes from.

Are you thinking that the clipboard is a feature of the Linux OS? It's not, it's implemented in the X Window System.

@Barmar What you're missing, is that I am trying to do this outsiide of the X environment.  Now before you react negatively to this, please understand that I can do this with pbcopy via termius SSH to a remote Mac system.  Sites like thiis one (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210615/how-to-copy-file-contents-to-the-local-clipboard-from-a-file-in-a-remote-machine) say that that can be done with xclip, but my experience is otherwise.  I will try to clarify the question.

@Barmar, I mentioned that I am doing this with PHP because more information is better.  That's all.

When you SSH to a remote Mac, you're not in its window environment either, so you can't access its clipboard.

It's magic, then, because it works for me @Barmar. I suppose it's like the bumblebee who supposedly doesn't know he xannit fly.  At a restaurant now (Merry Christmas) and out of town, but when i get home, tomorrow, I will make a video.

Here you are, @Barmar.  Demonstrating both pbcopy and pbpaste.  https://youtu.be/QGkymjB9qsQ

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152362/how-to-send-data-to-local-clipboard-from-a-remote-ssh-session
